# Flex Builder debug problem

Tags: apache-flex, debugging, flexbuilder, flashplayer-10, flashplayer-debug

I am running on Windows XP and recently updated Flash Player from v9 to v10.1. And Now, in the Debug Console under Flex Builder, I am getting a lot of debug statements(I think that is assembly). Below is an example, of what I get:
"
active: eax(737-757) ecx(738-758) ebx(3-797) esi(728-756)

@739 st    143112124(0) <- @3
    09002830  mov   143112124(0), ebx
                                 active: eax(737-757) ecx(738-758) ebx(3-797) esi(728-756)

@740 ldop  0(@3)
    09002836  mov   edx, 0(ebx)
                                 active: eax(737-757) ecx(738-758) edx(740-754) ebx(3-797) esi(728-756)

@741 ldop  20(@740)
    09002838  mov   edi, 20(edx)
                                 active: eax(737-757) ecx(738-758) edx(740-754) ebx(3-797) esi(728-756) edi(741-742)  *

@742 lea   4(@741) spans call
    0900283B  lea   edi, 4(edi)
                                 active: eax(737-757) ecx(738-758) edx(740-754) ebx(3-797) esi(728-756) edi(742-769)  *

@743 st    143111460(0) <- @742
    0900283E  mov   143111460(0), edi
                                 active: eax(737-757) ecx(738-758) edx(740-754) ebx(3-797) esi(728-756) edi(742-769)  *

@744 alloc 12
                         alloca 12 at 120 for @744 activation.size 132
                           stacksize 132 entries 17
                           -8(ebp) (6-792) alloc
                           -20(ebp) (7-792) alloc
                           -68(ebp) (8-792) alloc
                           -72(ebp) (0-793) arg
                           -76(ebp) (16-797) def
                           -80(ebp) (440-797) def
                           -80(ebp) 
                           -84(ebp) 
                           -88(ebp) (1-793) arg
                           -92(ebp) 
                           -96(ebp) 
                           -100(ebp) (2-793) arg
                           -104(ebp) 
                           -112(ebp) 
                           -116(ebp) 
                           -120(ebp) 
                           -132(ebp) (744-760) alloc
                                 active: eax(737-757) ecx(738-758) edx(740-754) ebx(3-797) esi(728-756) edi(742-769)  *

@745 imm   2
                                 active: eax(737-757) ecx(738-758) edx(740-754) ebx(3-797) esi(728-756) edi(742-769)  *

@746 st    0(@744) <- @745
    09002844  mov   -132(ebp), 2
                                 active: eax(737-757) ecx(738-758) edx(740-754) ebx(3-797) esi(728-756) edi(742-769)  *

@747 imm   139523392
                                 active: eax(737-757) ecx(738-758) edx(740-754) ebx(3-797) esi(728-756) edi(742-769)  *

@748 st    4(@744) <- @747
    0900284E  mov   -128(ebp), 139523392
                                 active: eax(737-757) ecx(738-758) edx(740-754) ebx(3-797) esi(728-756) edi(742-769)  *

@749 imm   136426472
                                 active: eax(737-757) ecx(738-758) edx(740-754) ebx(3-797) esi(728-756) edi(742-769)  *

@750 st    8(@744) <- @749
    09002855  mov   -124(ebp), 136426472
                                 active: eax(737-757) ecx(738-758) edx(740-754) ebx(3-797) esi(728-756) edi(742-769)  *

@751 ldop  16(@738)
STEAL any @738
                         alloca 4 at 80 for @738 activation.size 132
                           stacksize 132 entries 17
                           -8(ebp) (6-792) alloc
                           -20(ebp) (7-792) alloc
                           -68(ebp) (8-792) alloc
                           -72(ebp) (0-793) arg
                           -76(ebp) (16-797) def
                           -80(ebp) (440-797) def
                           -80(ebp) 
                           -84(ebp) (738-758) use
                           -88(ebp) (1-793) arg
                           -92(ebp) 
                           -96(ebp) 
                           -100(ebp) (2-793) arg
                           -104(ebp) 
                           -112(ebp) 
                           -116(ebp) 
                           -120(ebp) 
                           -132(ebp) (744-760) alloc
    0900285C  mov   -84(ebp), ecx
    0900285F  mov   ecx, 16(ecx)
                                 active: eax(737-757) ecx(751-759) edx(740-754) ebx(3-797) esi(728-756) edi(742-769)  *

@752 imm   1
                                 active: eax(737-757) ecx(751-759) edx(740-754) ebx(3-797) esi(728-756) edi(742-769)  *

@753 or    @738 @752
STEAL any @751
                         alloca 4 at 88 for @751 activation.size 132
                           stacksize 132 entries 17
                           -8(ebp) (6-792) alloc
                           -20(ebp) (7-792) alloc
                           -68(ebp) (8-792) alloc
                           -72(ebp) (0-793) arg
                           -76(ebp) (16-797) def
                           -80(ebp) (440-797) def
                           -80(ebp) 
                           -84(ebp) (738-758) use
                           -88(ebp) (1-793) arg
                           -92(ebp) (751-759) ldop 
                           -96(ebp) 
                           -100(ebp) (2-793) arg
                           -104(ebp) 
                           -112(ebp) 
                           -116(ebp) 
                           -120(ebp) 
                           -132(ebp) (744-760) alloc
    09002862  mov   -92(ebp), ecx
    09002865  mov   ecx, -84(ebp)
    09002868  or    ecx, 1
                                 active: eax(737-757) ecx(753-759) edx(740-754) ebx(3-797) esi(728-756) edi(742-769)  *
"

I am not sure, why it started, but any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just figured out the solution. It was caused by settings in Vizzy. I was experimenting with that tool and I guess it modified mm.cfg and produced a lot of details and trace statements. Fixed :)

Answer (score 0):

Using a beta player; this stuff is to be expected; isn't it?  Probably someone just didn't remove all the trace statements yet.

Comment: I am using the latest version of Flash Player 10.0.45.2, later I tried using Flash Player 9.0.262, but this still doesn't resolves the issue.

Comment: Your original post stated you that you were using Flash Player 10.1; which is not released yet.  Are you sure you've updated the debug player; which is a separate download / install process than installing the normal player? http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Comment: Yes, I know there are separate installer for flash player and flash debug player. I have installed both. Sorry for the confusion. I upgraded to stable version of Flash Player, which is v10.0.45.2. Any ideas, why this is happening ?